# CSV imported data table is not possible to use for histogram plot

Tags: r, data.table, histogram

I have created my own data set named as Kwality.csv in Excel and when I am executing above code I am not able to get histogram for the same data and it's throwing me error like this:

> Error in hist.default(mydata) : 'x' must be numeric

```
library(data.table)
mydata = fread("Kwality.csv", header = FALSE)
View(mydata)
hist(mydata)
```

Comment: `mydata` is a `data.frame`/`data.table` and not a single, numeric variable. You probably meant `hist(mydata$variablename)`

Comment: its still not working

Comment: You're going to have to give some more info. Check `is.numeric(mydata$variablename)` and make sure your variable is actually numeric. `hist` definitely works when provided the right input `hist(mtcars$mpg)` for example.

Comment: library(data.table)
mydata = fread("Kwality.csv",header = FALSE)
View(mydata)
hist(mydata)

this is the only code i did and the csv file that I have created in excel and imported in R to check the histogram of my personal report

Comment: You have to specify a variable/column to plot. `hist(mydata)` will not work but `hist(mydata$variablename)` where `variablename` is a reference to one of your numeric columns will. Take notice of the bit after the `$`.

Comment: @Harsh Samani, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce you work flow and exported xlsx-file into csv-file (using export to comma-separated file).

First, you should check what kind of character is used for variable and decimal places separation. In my case, for variable separation it is the `;` semicolon,  and the decimal places is "," comma.

Then you should choose the column, which you will use for the histogramm plot with the function`[[]]`. The data table itself is not a valid argument for `hist` function. Please see as below.

See below:
[image: file structure]

Taken this into consideration you cod execute your code:

```
library(data.table)
# load csv generatd by NORMSINV(RAND()) in Excel
mydata = fread("check.csv",header = FALSE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
mydata

#hist(mydata)
# Error in hist.default(mydata) : 'x' should be numeric
# does not work

# access by column, e.g. third colum - OK
hist(mydata[[3]])
```

Output:
[image: output]